# Need help with a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to determine $$\lim_{x \to 0} {x^2 \over \cos (3x) - 1}$$ My guess is that using the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} {\sin x \over x} = 1$ or perhaps $\lim_{x \to 0} {\tan x \over x} = 1$ could get me somewhere but I've tried it without much success.

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital's rule? (And, by the way, the two limits you quote are not 0 but 1).

Comment: I would like to try without L'Hospital first

Comment: What's with all the overkills? Obviously the OP isn't supposed to use that, it would be to easy.

Comment: @user1176517: But **why**? Do you hammer in nails with a screwdriver just to "try it without the hammer first"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Maybe he hasn't gotten that far in his course? Using overly-powerful tools is a definite impediment to learning. E.g. try learning basic group theory if you already "know" Burnside's theorem.

Comment: @EricTressler: L'Hospital isn't an "overly powerful tool" here. It is made _exactly_ for cases like this, and has just the amount of power needed for them.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I'm not missing anything. I shouldn't know about L'Hospitals rule yet, but of course no one can fail me would I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{x^2}{ \cos (3x) - 1}=-\frac{x^2(1+\cos3x)}{(1-\cos3x)(1+\cos3x)}\text{ if }1+\cos3x\ne0$$

$$\implies \frac{x^2}{ \cos (3x) - 1}=-\frac{x^2(1+\cos3x)}{\sin^23x}=-(1+\cos3x)\cdot\frac1{\left(\frac{\sin3x}{3x}\right)^2}\frac19$$

$$\implies\lim_{x \to 0} {x^2 \over \cos (3x) - 1}=-\frac{(1+1)}9$$

Comment: I like all solutions but this is the one I "should" have come up with.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos{(3x)}=1-2\sin^2{\dfrac{3x}{2}}\Longrightarrow \cos{3x}-1=-2\sin^2{\dfrac{3x}{2}}\approx -2(\dfrac{3x}{2})^2=-\dfrac{9}{2}x^2$$

Comment: I liked your answer better when it was just $$\cos{(3x)}=1-2\sin^2{\dfrac{3x}{2}}\Longrightarrow \cos{3x}-1=-2\sin^2{\dfrac{3x}{2}},$$ now you're just overkilling.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $\cos(3x)$ as $1 - \frac{(3x)^2}{2!} + \frac{(3x)^4}{4!} - ...$. Substitute that into your limit and...

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{\cos(3x) -1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\frac{9x^2}{2} + ... -1} = \frac{x^2}{-\frac{9}{2}x^2} = \frac{-2}{9}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\cos 3x\sim1-\frac92x^2$ for $x\to0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$ y\sim 0 \implies \cos(y)\sim 1-\frac{y^2}{2!} $$

Comment: I always use these two terms while $y\sim 0$ +1

Comment: What does $y\sim 0$ mean?

Comment: @BabakS.: It is handy. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: What does y∼0 mean?